# Semantic Issue "Property implementation must have its declaration in interface" while following Apple’s “Your First Mac App” tutorial

Tags: objective-c

I have been following [Apple’s “Your First Mac App” tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/Introduction.html) with Xcode 4.4 (4F250).

After [creating an outlet for the slider](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/ConfiguringtheWindow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012262-TP40012101-CH3-SW5), I cannot compile the app any more. There is the semantic issue: “Property implementation must have its declaration in interface.”

Similar questions on Stack Overflow seemed to be caused by wrong or missing `@property` declarations. However I have double- and triple-checked with the tutorial. The declaration reads:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSSlider *slider;
```

I would appreciate any help because I am totally stuck. I believe I have been following the tutorial to the letter and yet things go wrong. That’s not a good way to get started. :-/

In case it matters, here is the complete code of the header and the implementation.

*AppDelegate.h*

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSSlider *slider;

- (IBAction)mute:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)takeFloatValueforVolumeFrom:(id)sender;

@end
```

*AppDelegate.m*

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize slider;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
}

- (IBAction)mute:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)takeFloatValueforVolumeFrom:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Comment: This might be an interesting aside. When I look at `AppDelegate.h` (here is a [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1468510/share/2012-07/25-png-D0l9wj/index.html)), there is a filled-in circle next to the `slider` property. But the Connections Inspector for the App Delegate shows an exclamation mark for slider outlet, complaining that _AppDelegate does not have an outlet named slider._

Comment: How did you connect the outlet in IB?  I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted, so it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: @rdelmar I Ctrl-dragged to the header file and filled in the fields as described in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my problem was just some hiccup on the part of Xcode. Today, I did just the same things, and everything worked out.

Thanks to everybody who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment says to me that you have not properly linked the slider property with the xib file. You need to have a circle and not an exclamation point next to the properly. In my experience this usually causes a runtime error... so I am not 100% positive this will fix your compilation issue.